# gvim: go to a specific file with multiple windows and multiple tabs open

Tags: windows, vim, vi, gedit

I am in the process of shifting editors from gedit to gvim. In gedit, when I have multiple gedit windows open, each having multiple tabs, I can click Documents which will list all files in all tabs and windows open and I can go to any one of those by clicking from the list.

How can I do this in gvim? The Buffers button in gvim lists only the files open in the current window.

Thank you!

Comment: `click` is something that you'll need to unlearn if you want to switch to gvim/vim. I think that what you're asking is not possible, but I don't really see why would you need to have multiple windows for the same project.

Comment: @draevor: if you use `:set mouse=a`, you can use your mouse to click into the text, and also in the names of the files opened by `:tabe`, among many other things...

Comment: @Nicolás I'm not saying it's not possible to do a lot of things with the mouse (particularly in gvim with menus enabled), but that it kinda defeats the purpose. You'll be able to do most (all?) of the things faster with the keyboard.

Comment: Moving your hand to the mouse takes longer than a keyboard shortcut already, at least in ViM! ^^

Comment: I've just stated that it's possible to do many things with the mouse in VIM. A very different thing is if using that device is the best option, and after some while using VIM, almost anybody will say that the keyboard will be almost always the fastest option available... ^^

Comment: I don't think that what you are asking for can be done with gVim. If you have multiple OS windows open for gVim, I think each is its own process - they don't know about each other. However, Vim has its own concept of windows, and if you take some time to get familiar with them, you might fall in love. I did. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GVim is a single window program. If you have two GUI windows you have two separate GVim processes that can't really talk to each other.

Switching from a "normal" editor to Vim is not a walk in the park: you'll have to adapt to Vim's mindset for your switch to be successful.

Vim's "windows" and "tabs" are badly named and provide much confusion among newcomers.

In "normal" editors, a tab (or a GUI window for those without tabs) is a 1:1 representation of a file and a GUI window is a collection of tabs/files. The system is deterministic: as long as you didn't close it, you can equate the first window with `Controlers/`, the second tab of the second window with `Models/User.php` and so on. Because that "normal" editor is a multi-window program and all those tabs and windows are children of one process it's easy for the main process to provide a list of all of its windows and tabs.

In GVim, the two GUI windows are created by two separate processes: GUI window #1 as no knowledge of GUI window #2. Furthermore, Vim's concept of "windows" and "tabs" is not deterministic at all. A "window" is only a view of a buffer and this buffer can be any buffer currently in memory. A "tab" is a collection of windows and its name is automatically set to the buffer currently displayed in the active "window". In an extreme scenario you could end up with the same buffer displayed in `x` windows in `y` tabs.

So, because of GVim design, I don't think it's possible without a lot of work to mimic Gedit's behaviour.

Because it's too easy, specially for new users, to mix up their "buffers", "windows" and "tabs" I'd advise you to stay away from "tabs", at least for a moment, and learn to use "buffers" and "windows" to their fullest.

Vim's default behaviour is to ask you to save the current buffer before replacing it in the current window with another buffer. This, I think is the reason so many people turn to using tabs in Vim. `set hidden` and `set switchbuf=useopen` solve this "problem" and allow you to open many buffers in the same window. Switching buffers is super easy with native tools: `:sb <tab>` and sexy/powerful with 3rd party tools like [CtrlP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736) or [others](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=buffer%20switching&script_type=&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search). If you are used to having different parts of your project in different windows (one for `Controlers/`, one for `Models/` and one for `Views/`, for example, or one for the backend and one for the frontend) you can use Vim's tabs for that.